# Python - return constructor arguments names without instantiating

Tags: python, parameters, constructor, python-2.x

Suppose that I have defined a class with a constructor.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
```

Now I would like to make an instance of `Person`, but suppose that I forgot what I should pass to the constructor.
Since I have defined default arguments, I can do

```
dummy_person = Person()
print dummy_person.__init__.__code__.co_varnames
```

Which will let me see what are the arguments, so that I can make a new `Person`, this time passing the appropriate name and age.

The question is: how can I achieve a similar result without having to instantiate a `dummy_person` first? In other words: can I access the argument list of the constructor by only knowing the class name?

**Edit**: Here is how I am planning to use this feature.

```
args_names = CircleTrajectory.__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1:]
args = {}
for arg_name in args_names:
    args.append(float(input("Insert " + arg_name + ": ")))

my_circle = CircleTrajectory(*args)
```

For this to work, we need to have a `CircleTrajectory` class defined, and we need to assume that all the parameters of its constructor are floats. The last assumption does not exactly appeal to me very much, but I think it is safe, since all these objects need to be created by the final user by typing the values in a GUI.

Comment: Whle you can do that, it seems like you are asking a wrong question here, as this seems to be one messed up solution. Could you share the full use case this affects?

Comment: If you want to create an instance from user input, shouldn't that logic be part of the class itself (this is rhetorical question; the answer is yes)? Consider making it a class method rather than faffing around with introspection (`my_circle = CircleTrajectory.from_input()`), especially given that you won't be able to tell what type of input is required from outside.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, sure! That actually opens a whole new world of possibilities here. I have a small doubt still: is the `from_input` method a `@classmethod`, and does it call a constructor inside of it?

Comment: 1. Yes, a `@classmethod`; and 2. Yes, usually in the form `return cls(...)` once you've got all the necessary input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the same properties on the actual class `Person`:

```
>>> Person.__init__.__code__.co_varnames
('self', 'name', 'age')
```

Comment: Great, works for me! But I am actually surprised that it works. After all, `__init__` is not a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`; on the contrary, it is bound to the particular instance. I guess here we are dealing with `__init__` as a piece of code, rather of as a function call. Any further insight would be treasured.

Comment: @Antonio instance methods still exist on the class prior to instantiation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right; after all, `__init__` needs to exist so that it can be called when you instantiate for the first time.

Comment: Do you happen to know how if there is a method to get the default values as well?

Comment: @Antonio Yep - see this Gist: https://gist.github.com/OrangeFlash81/fb4e4e734a7a52591b01a73fa8e4581d

Answer (score 1):

You can use `help(Person)` or `help(Person.__init__)`